# How do i require a user to enter a password from InstallShield LE before installation?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installshield

I'm using VS2010 with Installshield LE. I've created a project in the past that required the user to enter a password before installing. But I can't for the life of remember how I did it. I must have gone through all the setting 5 times.

Can someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: For anyone who's asking the same question, you can set password to protect Setup.exe in the Release Wizard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was provided to me by Madusree at InstallShield, on their forums. But its worth repeating it here because I found no info on this subject elsewhere...

> Hi,
>   You can reset the password by navigating to Releases view and Setup.exe Tab and reset the password in "Password Protect Launcher" Field.
>   Thanks,
>   Madu, InstallShield Software Engineer

Thanks Madu...

Answer (score 0):

I think you used a Visual Studio setup project. InstallShield LE doesn't support serial number validation (it requires a commercial license).

For both of them, the approach is the same:

- go to dialogs page
- add the customer information dialog
- configure the serial number validation

Comment: This wasn't a serial number type of validation. It was just a simple "Enter a password and I'll start the install process" Type thing. Somewhere in the configuration process it asked if I wanted to Password Protect the installation. I selected "yes", and then it just asked what password I wanted to use.